# Сopy function from set to multimap

Tags: c++, insert, set, copy, multimap

I have a function:

```
void DBMAP::addM(Volkov_1* b)
{
    setMAP.insert(pair<int, Volkov_1*>(*b->x, b));
}
```

This function passes data from set to multimap. And she copes with her duty, but there is a moment of double ownership. It is necessary not to pass the existing pointer, but to copy. I don't understand how to implement this. I ask for help.
Here's a multimap:

```
class DBMAP
{
private:
    multimap < int, Volkov_1* > setMAP;
public:
    DBMAP() {};
    DBMAP(DB& db)
    {
     db.copyM(*this);
    };
    void addM(Volkov_1* b)
    {
     setMAP.insert(pair<int, Volkov_1*>(*b->x, b));
    };
    ~DBMAP() {};
};
```

Here's a set:

```
class DB
{
private:
    struct pred
    {
        bool operator()(Volkov_1* a, Volkov_1* b)
            const
        {
            return *(a->x) < *(b->x);
        }
    };
    set <Volkov_1*, pred> MySet;
public:
    DB() {};
    void add(Volkov_1* obj)
    {
        pair < set<Volkov_1*, pred>::iterator, bool> ptr;
        Volkov_1* c = obj;
        ptr = MySet.insert(c);
        if (ptr.second == false)
            delete c;
    };
    void copyM(DBMAP& dbm)
    {
        for (set <Volkov_1*, pred>::iterator it = MySet.begin(); it != MySet.end(); ++it)
            dbm.addM(*it);
    };
    void DBcopy(DB& db)
    {
        set <Volkov_1*, pred>::iterator it = db.MySet.begin(), it0 = db.MySet.begin();
        advance(it0, db.MySet.size() / 2);
        for (; it != it0; ++it)
        {
            Volkov_1* b = *it;
            b->copy(*this);
        }
    };
    DB(DBMAP& dbmap) {};
    ~DB(){};
};
```

Comment: If you want to copy an object `T* obj` you would do something like `new T(*obj)` and rely on the `T` copy constructor to make the copy.  But be aware that now you have to resolve the ownership question of who owns both objects.

Comment: What about `std::unique_ptr<T>` or  ``std::shared_ptr<T>``?  Like that: `multimap < int, std::unique_ptr<Volkov_1> >`.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 how to write it? I've tried

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ ok. But how do you change the function later?

Comment: @АртёмВолков I won't do the memory management manually, that's too error prone, and hard to get right. Better use what I proposed, it's purposed for such use cases.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I understand what you want to suggest, but I do not understand how to write it

Comment: @АртёмВолков _"But how do you change the function later?"_ I don't know what you mean? You probably need to elaborate that better in your question. Provide a [mcve], most of the code in your example apparently isn't relevant.